# What's the fastest cloud sync for gazillions of small files?

Tags: windows-7, sync, cloud

I work on several different machines (office/home/laptop) and I like to have my whole development environment with me and in sync all the time. That enables me to be productive right away without forcing me to install things. A few well crafted batch files set up all my paths for me.

In my development environment I have a ton of tools and a lot of source code (don't worry it's in SCM's too), as well as documents and so on. It's dominated by a very very large number of small files in the 4-8K range. Some of them also change quite frequently, since I'm doing compiles.

I tried running succesfully it from a fast usb stick/disk, but I'd like a cloud sync solution instead. I've used dropbox for a while, and while it works okay, it's not fast.

So I'm looking for a very fast cloud sync tool that will detect changes on the fly and work well with a huge number of small files.

I've tried:

- dropbox
- wuala
- sygarsync
- CX
- Symform
- Jungledisk

and a few more, and they all have the same problem: uploading small files is too slow. I suspect it has to do with each file getting a separate request, and then the http overhead just piles up i guess.

I'm using Windows 7 x64 as my OS

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want since you want to detect changes on the fly. But for my own project I use turtoiseSVN with www.unfuddle.com

If I am done with work on my laptop I simply click "SVN Commit" and after confirming the changes it instantly uploads to unfuddle.com (it's really fast with small files!)

At home I click SVN Update and it instantly downloads the new files. So I can continu working at home. This is way faster than dropbox and also creates no conflicted copies.

You should give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a virtual machine for your workplace. A virtual machine is just a bunch of files you can copy, move and backup. But also you can run the vm from the most OS. 2nd step is to install a virtual machine server where you can remotely access your vm thus you don't need to copy the vm again and again. Personally it's the best way to separate my computer from the work files and to backup my work files and to test new program or os.  A complete Windows XP in a vm is only 3GB size.